# Base de datos en Amazon Web Services

Tags: mysql, aws, amazon

Tengo un problema a la hora de conectar una base de datos a un EC2 en amazon. Meto las credenciales que me da el RDS de Amazon al crear una base de datos mysql y no me deja conectarme desde el Workbench, he probado mil maneras y me resulta imposible.

Es una situación compleja. Creé un sitio con la herramienta de creación de wordpress bitnami en Amazon. Pero al verme limitada, decidí hacer la página con el código de 0. Ya la tengo hecha, y solo he tenido que cambiar archivos en donde se encontraba el .htaccess y quitar el index.php de wordpress, modificándole el nombre. Por si en un futuro quisiera recuperar la página de wordpress.

Claro. Yo sé que wordpress necesita de una base de datos para conectarse, el problema es que no sé cómo podría acceder yo a esa base de datos que me creó el ec2 por defecto para poder insertar las tablas de mi nueva página.

También he intentado crear una base de datos externa a Amazon, pero en ninguno de los 3 casos que he probado me dejaba conectarme a algo externo. No sé si esto será habitual para que solamente use sus productos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero que no sea muy tarde y puedas seguir con tu pagina, solo paso por aca para darte algunas recomendaciones.

- Crea la BD en el servicio RDS de amazon, si tu BD es en una cuenta diferente a donde esta tu  servidor recuerda activarle **Publicly accessible** (no es recomendado porque tendrian acceso a tu BD desde cualquier red pero puede ayudarte).
- Recuerda configurar los Security Groups de tus EC2, el puerto 3306 que es por defecto el de mysql.